# How to close rosgscreen using onkeyevent() in scene graph xml ?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I have created ConfirmSignout.xml scene in. main.brs to show some dialog pop-up with two buttons.
If I call dismissSignoutdialog() in onKeyevent, pop-up and rosgscreen has to close and focus will be on the previous screen. But for me if I call dismissSignoutdialog(), rosgscreen is not getting closed.

could anyone help me on this.

**Main.brs**

```
sub ConfirmSignOUT() As Object
    screen = CreateObject("roSGScreen")
    m.port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
    screen.setMessagePort(m.port)
    scene = screen.CreateScene("ConfirmSignout")
    screen.show()
    while(true)
        msg = wait(0, m.port)
        msgType = type(msg)
        if msgType = "roSGScreenEvent"
          if msg.isScreenClosed() then 
            return -1
            exit while
          end if 
        end if
    end while
End sub
```

**ConfirmSignout.xml**

```
<component name = "ConfirmSignout" extends = "Scene" >
  <script type = "text/brightscript" >
    <![CDATA[
     sub init()
        m.top.backgroundURI ="pkg:/images/rsgde_bg_hd.jpg"
        dialog = createObject("roSGNode", "Dialog")
        'dialog.backgroundUri = "pkg:/images/rsgde_dlg_bg_hd.9.png"
        dialog.optionsDialog = false
        dialog.title = "Alert"
        dialog.message = "Are you sure you want to Signout?"
        dialog.buttons=["No","Yes"]
        dialog.visible = true
        m.top.dialog = dialog
    end sub

    sub dismissSignoutdialog()
        m.top.dialog.close = true
    end sub

    function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean
        button_val = m.top.dialog.buttonSelected
        if not press then
            if key = "OK"
                if(button_val = 0)
                    dismissSignoutdialog()
                    return true
                else if (button_val = 1)    
                    print "m.top";m.top
                    'return true
                end if  
            end if
        end if
      'return false
    end function

    ]]>

  </script>

  <children >

    <Label
      id = "SignoutLable" />

  </children>

</component>
```

Comment: print ``msgType  and  ``msg

Comment: So this is a signout page? You wanted to sign out and close the page and redirect to some other page. Right?  You can use `group` for this. And do you think your `onKeyEvent` function is correct?  What do you mean by `if not press`' and you are again saying  ` key = "OK"` . the key won't work till `press` is true

Comment: I am new user for BrightScript.
I would like to implement onKeyEvent( ) in one of my Test.brs file. I this possible to do that without mentioning onKeyEvent( ) function in any script file. I am just putting onKeyEvent( ) in Test.brs file but function is not getting called while pressing remote buttons.
Please help...

Comment: @Maddy your issue is solved or it's pending?